# Link direct to advertisement broken

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, advertising

I would like to receive some information about advertising on Stack Overflow--the link located at the bottom of the page is not currently working.

Comment: It just redirects to http://stackexchange.com/about/contact

Comment: The page it links to contains text reading "To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at ads@stackexchange.com, call +1 (212)232-8280 and select option "2" at the auto-attendant to reach our ad sales team. Our business hours are Monday through Friday, 9am to 5pm Eastern time zone in the United States."

Comment: There is an issue. The link is `http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/2776/2751/0/4de3c60f719c4dfcb1a57531c7050090/0` for me and isn't resolving

Comment: +1 for looking to advertise your product the right way. I always check out companies that advertise here, and look forward to seeing your ads!

Answer (score 28):

Oops. Something went weird with that link; we'll fix it ASAP.

In the meantime, you can reach our ad sales folks by emailing ads@stackexchange.com or calling +1 (212)232-8280 and selecting option "2" at the auto-attendant. Our business hours are Monday through Friday, 9am to 5pm Eastern time zone in the United States.

Comment: Tempted to flag "it is spam"... can I resist? Ahhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: @jbal It certainly meets the spam criteria: They're trying to sell ads! Complete with business hours! Kill it!

Comment: @jball ಠ_ಠ ಠ_ಠ ಠ_ಠ